# BottomNavBar With Navigation Component not responding

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, bottomnavigationview

So I am using Navigation Component with Menu items to create a BottomNavigation bar . However the problem occurs when i have fully run the error free code and the menu items are completely unresponsive. It only remains stagnant in one Fragment without navigating to others when clicking.

Here is the activity where the navhost fragment is located:

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var navController: NavController
private val binding: ActivityHomeBinding by lazy {
    ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    setUpBottomNavigation()
}

private fun setUpBottomNavigation() {
    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
    binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)

}
```

}

Here is the xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Home.HomeActivity">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="673dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_without_splash" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="411dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/lightGray"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_tint"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_tint"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

heres the menu item.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/start2"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:title="Data"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_mms_24"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:title="Profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"/>
```

[image: nav graph 1]

Comment: So does your navigation graph have destination with the same IDs as menu items? Please include your navigation graph XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by doing this in your activity file

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {
private var _binding: FragmentLoginBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    binding.tohomepagebutton.setOnClickListener {

        /*
        since you are using nav graph instead of using intents to switch between activities,
        you can invoke the actions on the navgraph to navigate to the preferred destination
         to understand better check https://medium.com/swlh/android-navigation-component-part-1-6191323eaf39
         https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started*/

        NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_home2)

    }

    return binding.root

}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

}